# How to Access Ubuntu files, while running from live cd

Tags: permissions, lightdm, live-cd

I wrote this Code `greeter-show-manual-login=true` in my Ubuntu `etc/lightDM.conf`, but when I restart my System ubuntu can't load it!

Now I access this file with live cd, but when I open it and delete code, it does not permit me to save!

This picture shows the file `lightDM.conf` on my Main Ubuntu drive:

[image]

And this is for `lightDM.conf` file, when I want to clean and save it !

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the way Linux based systems handle file permissions.

To solve it, instead of editing the file directly, type `gksudo gedit /path/to/file` in a terminal, edit and save it. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> is a handy shortcut to open terminal.

To get the full path to file, when you open it in Nautilus (the file browser in your first screenshot), select the file, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. You will see the full path selected in location bar. Replace `/path/to/file` with the path you see in location bar.

It will very likely be `/media/ubuntu/some-long-hexadecimal-string/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

Note that `gksudo` should be used carefully. Improper usage has the potential to cause irreparable damage. I advise you to read about the following concepts before attempting to use `gksudo` by yourself in future.

- Users and Groups in Linux
- File system permissions, `chmod`,`chown`
- Previlege escalation, `sudo`, `gksudo`